# NextJS - Best way to set a cookie in App router server component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, cookies

I have a requirement to increment a flag in the database and set a cookie with an expiry time of 5 minutes when a page loads, and the next time the page loads, check if the cookie is expired or not and increment the flag and set a new cookie if it's expired.

Currently, I'm planning to use a Route handler for setting the cookie and calling the Route handler when the server component loads(the server component is used because I want to increment the database flag and the page is a public page so can't use client-side data updation due to security).

Is this the right way or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to call a Route handler. If you are in a server component, you can call `cookies()` from there.

See https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies for details.

Comment: Yeah, I can use cookies() to read cookie from server components, but my requirement is to set a cookie. HTTP does not allow setting cookies after streaming starts, so you must use .set() in a Server Action or Route Handler.